# Problems doing insert in hibernate in central many-to many relationship tables with the same id (it works doing it manually but not automatically)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I started developing an hibernate application and doing the inserts mannualy, I made a database with a lot of many to many relationships where I have to insert in the central tables created by the relationships too. I had some problems looking for the way of doing the inserts in those tables and trying not to have conflicts doing the inserts with the same ID, for example a linguist can have more than one especialisation so the table would look something like this:

[image: as you can see different linguists can have same specialisation]

so I found out a way to do so with this code:

```
//create the linguist

Linguista user=new Linguista(1,"stack","overflow","mail@gmail.com","burundi","1-5","mylink","linkerio");

//create the specializations

Especializacion esp1 = new Especializacion(1,"espacial");

Especializacion esp2 = new Especializacion(2,"informatic");

//the I add the especializations to the users table and the user to the especializations table

user.getEspecializaciones().add(esp1);

user.getEspecializaciones().add(esp2);

esp1.getLinguistas().add(user);

esp2.getLinguistas().add(user);


//then create the transaction and save them in the database:

tx = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(user);
             
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.close();
```

In this case it works perfectly and if I repeat the ID or the name of the especialization with another ID, Hibernate finds out that there is a record with that name and doesn't create another one with the same name and different ID, linking it to the linguist just like in the image.

The problem is that now I am doing this same process automatically, taking the info from a web page with selenium and then inserting it in the database and I get this error:

org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [servicios.Servicio#49]

This is the code:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();

//create the linguist object

Linguista nuevo = new Linguista(); 

session.beginTransaction();
    
//taking the biggest id to do a +1 to that id (coudn't do it with the auto increment)

Linguista lingusitas=  (Linguista) session.createQuery("FROM Linguista ORDER BY LinguistaID DESC").setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();

int newid= lingusitas.getLinguistaid();

newid++;

nuevo.setLinguistaid(newid);

nuevo.setPlataforma("stackoverflow");

session.close();
                
// taking the data with Selenium

nuevo = RecogerDatosCuenta(nuevo, numero);

nuevo = RecogerDatosUsuario(nuevo);

nuevo = RecogerDatosExperiencia(nuevo);

System.out.println(nuevo.toString());

//inserting that linguist

session = factory.openSession();

session.clear();

session.beginTransaction();

session.save(nuevo);

session.getTransaction().commit();

session.close();
```

Here the recogerdatosexperiencia function, where I link the especilaization with the user:

```
session = factory.openSession();

session.beginTransaction();

Especializacion espec=(Especializacion)session.createQuery("FROM Especializacion ORDER BY EspecializacionID DESC").setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();

int newid= espec.getEspecializacionid();

newid++;

Especializacion newesp = new Especializacion(newid, datos.get(i));

linguista.getEspecializaciones().add(newesp);

newesp.getLinguistas().add(linguista);

return linguista;
```

I tried doing it with merge instead of save and it does the insert perfectly, but generates new file in the especialization table, with the same name of the especialization but different ID.

[image: merging instead of saving]

how can I do to save the linguist without generating new especialization fields if they are already in the databae, just like in the first image?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You need to try to find an existing `Especializacion` first and use that one if it exists

Comment: @crizzis thanks for you answer!!. Ok I was thinking about doing it like that but, how can I "use" an existing Especializacion  with a new Linguista?. Just creating a query where I first compare if that especializacion exists and then how can I link it with the Linguista?

Comment: Just query for a specialization with the same `especializacionNombre` and add it to `linguista.getEspecializaciones()` instead of a new object